# identification of species of snake

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify this colorful snake found at Pulau Ubin in Singapore?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the paradise tree snake ([*Chrysopelea paradisi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopelea_paradisi)). It is a colubrid snake and is common in south-east asia. See [this site](http://www.blogiversity.org/blogs/cstanton/archive/2010/04/24/7-spectacular-gliding-animals.aspx) for a better image.

Comment: And great flying snake movies at http://www.flyingsnake.org/